# How to replace multiple maps in rxjs observable array?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to return only 3 item from array.

Can you advise better solution? Thanks!

```
loadAsk!: Observable<any[]>;

this.loadAsk.pipe(
  map(arr => arr.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)),
  map((item: any[]) => [item[0], item[1], item[2]])
).subscribe(res => {
  //code
})
```

Comment: you can use 'slice' method of Array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to pull up only first 3 numbers? you dont need a pipe or observable to do that

```
item:any[] = [loadAsk[0], loadAsk[1], loadAsk[2]]
```